# MySql query with arduino and sim900

Tags: mysql, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sim900

I'm doing a project with Arduino Uno and the Sim900 module. I want to do a query to a MySql server with PHP and the Arduino code. 
Could you help me doing the Arduino code?
I've already written the database connection and the query with PHP, the only thing I need is to do the query, read the answer of the database and print them in the serial monitor.
If it helps me, I will mark as the best answer.
Thanks

Comment: you may make `POST` or `GET` requests from sim900 to your PHP app on the server, which can then interact with the MySQL DB and execute commands and return responses.

Comment: Have a look at this post  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/using-a-sim900a-to-send-sensor-data-to-a-website/